# UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top with a UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I feel this should be simple to accomplish but for some reason im lost.
I have a button that will scroll a UICollectionView so the cell at an given IndexPath is top of the screen. problem is that the method does not take into account the supplementary header view. so :

```
collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexP, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

actually means the cell disappears under the header. How best to resolve so that calling `UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top`scrolls to the top under the header?

in the viewDidLoad of my UICollectioViewController

```
let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Comment: I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638855/scrolltoitem-at-indexpath-at-top-hides-cell-under-header-when-sectionheaderspin/51250268#51250268