# scrollToItem at indexPath at .top hides cell under header when sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Using the following configuration:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

let collectionViewController = UICollectionViewController(view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

The following code will scroll to the given index path but the item will be under and covered by its header:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(section: 0, row: 2)
collecitonView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

How do I get the collection view to scroll to the item at indexPath without the item being covered by its section header when sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds is set to true?

Comment: Did you find anyway to fix it?

Comment: No I didn't. I ended up setting the layoutAttributes for each of my sticky headers in a custom UICollectionViewLayout.  I did this by overriding the `override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?` function. Let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 13):

It seems like a iOS framework's bug. I'm using this way.

```
 guard let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    return
} 
let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: layout.frame.minY - headerHeight)
collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Wrestled an issue where this was helpful 

Comment: Worked for me after I also subtracted my UIEdgeInset top amount.

Comment: Worked for me without the need to subtract header height!